# Automatic Temperature Controller with Thermistor (Incandescent BULB)

Tags: light, thermistor, dimmer, ptc

I'm new in this site
And sorry for my english language..

I need a circuit for my little oven.

I use an incandescent bulb (4x100W) for heating, and I want make a dimmer circuit to change output using a temperature sensor (ptc or ntc).

I have an AC Light Dimmer I want to modify. I want to change the potentiometer to ptc but I can't find a 470k ptc...

What are your ideas for it?

---

[image]

Can I use this circuit?

With PIC16F88

Comment: Show us the schematic diagram of your existing dimmer.

Comment: If you do replace the pot with a thermistor, be aware that the thermistor and related wiring is potentially live and dangerous. [Is the dimmer potentiometer used as a voltage divider or just as a rheostat?](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/11048/whats-the-difference-between-a-potentiometer-and-a-rheostat)

Comment: How about PWM a solid state relay to turn the bulbs on and off, with the pulse width set by the error signal from your temp sensor, set point.

Comment: @DaveTweed I have wall type dimmer I don't have schematic
http://i63.tinypic.com/14o29hc.jpg

Comment: @GeorgeHerold Is it problem constantly on-off for incandescent bulbs? I can use basic relay circuit with ntc or ptc...

Comment: @jms 
Well, thank you for caution.. I think use stepper motor for change value of pot?

Comment: Think I'd recommend high-freq. PWM controlling a power MOSFET to control the output to the bulbs. That way you can use any ptc or ntc thermistor you want; just set your PWM control chip to use a "standard value" thermistor. Using PWM+power MOSFET gives much better efficiency than resistive dimming methods ;)

Comment: @RobhercKV5ROB 
Thank you very much for your advice.. Can you recommend a circuit about this PWM and Mosfet project? meantime I must set max. temperature..

I find this video 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PKEJApZ6TFw

Comment: The fact that you talk about replacing the potentiometer on the dimmer with a temperature sensor suggests that you want a closed-loop control of temperature. This cannot be done by a simple hack of a dimmer. You'll need to learn a good deal more electronics first. And PWM control of a light bulb is not a great idea, since you would need to isolate the MOSFETs to keep from getting shocked. You might as well stick with the dimmer triacs.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast 
Can I use a PID and SSR for Bulbs? May it problem ? And can you advice PWM circuit for 4x100W bulbs

Comment: Yes you can use a PID and SSR, but it's not simple, and you need to learn a lot more first. And my advice about PWM circuit is to use the triac in a dimmer. Learn about triacs.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast 
Is wiring true for this application?

http://ecorenovator.org/forum/attachments/tools/2456d1345670408-pid-temperature-controller-wiring-diagram-gif

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast
Can you advice circuit for PWM and Powered MOSFET?

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example citcuit for using a thermistor & PWM controller (you could hack a dc/dc converter controller to do the job) as a thermostat to run your lights. The xfmr is to drop your AC mains voltage down to whatever supply voltage your MCU needs (a wall-wart would work, as long as your GND isn't isolated).

[image]

Comment: Thank you a lot of dear.. What is value D1, D2, and MCU

And last thing is how can I set max. temperature..?

Comment: D1 & D2 are diodes, any diode rated to the voltage & current will work. As for setting the temperature, that depends on what MCU you choose to use. With some, a variable resistor would work well; for others, can set temperature with software.