# Q: Whats the schematic of this Potentiometer

Tags: circuit-analysis

Just wondering what's the wiring, kinda confused on how this actually looks on a schematic.

[image]

Does this look correct?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fGzjXb.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: You could always read the rest of the datasheet.

Comment: I did, I never got onto anything

Comment: Perhaps if you know [what the difference between a potentiometer and a rheostat](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/11048/whats-the-difference-between-a-potentiometer-and-a-rheostat) is, it would help.

Comment: Oh interesting, so its just a single variable resistor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a (simulated) variable resistor between pins 5 and 6. From Wikipedia:

[image]

Of course there are some differences with real resistor, such as the requirement that both ends of the resistor must always remain within the power supply rails of the chip for proper operation. The "wiper resistance" is in series with the "element resistance" which means some nonlinearity that will vary with voltage of the simulated rheostat and the supply voltage.

Comment: How would one use it in a feedback loop in an amplifier, to automate gain?

Comment: You could use it as the feedback resistor in an inverting amplifier, in conjunction with a fixed resistor R. Gain = -Rf/R. Or swap resistors so you get 1/gain proportional to Rf. Etc. But it will likely introduce some distortion.

Comment: Would it be too much to see a schematic on how its hooked up? I am confused on the wiper pin because I want to use an arduino to control the resistance values

Comment: This sounds like a new question- it will have to get int design of a single supply amplifier probably, so more than just this question scope.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are right.

you can find on page 2 of the [datasheet](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/22060a.pdf) this schema :

[image]